# GoogleMapApi looses precision depending the country you execute

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm using http://code.google.com/p/php-google-map-api/. I made an application to get latitude and longitude of different street names. But when I execute this script from outside my country this precision is lost and I can't geolocate all the streets.

I think that Google keeps a different index depending of the country you are. How can I change the country (or locale) of my API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once we had an experiment on Mobile Network Development. We used *GoogleMaps* as basic geolocation tool for mapping/locating and measuring Base Stations characteristics. As the result, we've got into trouble very quickly.

We needed rather precise data (*about 5 meters maximum deviation*) and what do you think ? The street which was **2 km** long (*what was measured after experiment with required accuracy*) was calculated as **1.7 km** in *GoogleMaps*.

Moreover, most of the patches (*ground photos*) that are shown on map, overlaps each other in different way. Actually, it depends on country and on the precision of shooting, because some countries are more detailed some are not (*very not*).

Speaking about streets, this deviation is rather considerable to say that it can be precise. *GoogleMaps* should not be treated as the precise geolocation tool in any case, especially if high precision is required (*street level is already above-normal precision*).

So, I propose you not to take into account this data very seriously. Otherwise *GoogleMaps* is a very nice security breach for all of us. Imagine that You have **nuclear bomb** or **missle** and you already know where to direct it with accuracy of several meters, sitting somewhere in the middle of the Sahara. Here you are ...

Comment: Which tool did you used in the end?

Comment: @raimonbosch, to perform our task we were limited (or extended) to usual, high quality GPS receiver. Only these values you can really trust.

Comment: @raimonbosch, can you please tell me what for do you need such data or service ? Maybe you achieve it another way.